Concerning prompt change in Mac terminal
Normally, my Mac's terminal prompt is home@Primarys-MacBook-Pro. When I connect to an unsecured network at my hotel, the prompt in my terminal changes to home@JUSTIN-s-Note20. My name isn't Justin, and it appears to be referring to "Justin"'s Samsung Galaxy Note20. Is this evidence that my computer is compromised? Is it the result of a known phenomenon? I find it unfathomable that my terminal prompt could so easily be changed to contain someone else's name.

Thanks for posting. This is valuable to keep visible since anyone searching for the problem with the same wording as you will find the main thread on why this happens.
